Migrated Spring Boot Project from MySQL to PostgreSQL
We want to migrate a Spring Boot project in which we use JPA over a very large MySQL database (500+ tables) to a postgreSQL database.
After a series of specific changes (change of reserved words, change of column types etc.) I managed to start the server without instant errors related to the database.
However, after about 2-3 minutes after opening the server, I noticed that the IDE reports OutOfMemory error (during opening the server).
I activated debug for hibernate and noticed a lot of operations that it performs.
Hibernate debug output (thousands of lines with the same operation on different tables/ relations):
IP: D:31-10-2024 10:49:01.922 [main] [39mDEBUG[0;39m org.hibernate.orm.sql.ast.create - Registration of TableGroup [org.hibernate.sql.ast.tree.from.LazyTableGroup@562f3986] with identifierForTableGroup [ro.rpss.foundations.persistence.scholarship.entity.ScholarshipHolder.scholarshipFile.scholarshipConfiguration.scholarshipConfigurationSelectionCriteria.scholarshipConfiguration.infoScholarshipConfiguration.scholarshipConfiguration.applicationCalendarScholarshipConfiguration.scholarshipConfiguration.studySeries.studyPromotion.studyProgrammeReference.currentRevision.programmeReference.currentRevision.entityReference] for NavigablePath [ro.rpss.foundations.persistence.scholarship.entity.ScholarshipHolder.scholarshipFile.scholarshipConfiguration.scholarshipConfigurationSelectionCriteria.scholarshipConfiguration.infoScholarshipConfiguration.scholarshipConfiguration.applicationCalendarScholarshipConfiguration.scholarshipConfiguration.studySeries.studyPromotion.studyProgrammeReference.currentRevision.programmeReference.currentRevision.entityReference] 
IP: D:31-10-2024 10:49:01.922 [main] [39mDEBUG[0;39m org.hibernate.orm.sql.ast.create - Created new SQL alias : er44946_0
IP: D:31-10-2024 10:49:01.922 [main] [39mDEBUG[0;39m org.hibernate.orm.sql.ast.create - Registration of TableGroup [org.hibernate.sql.ast.tree.from.LazyTableGroup@512a49] with identifierForTableGroup [ro.rpss.foundations.persistence.scholarship.entity.ScholarshipHolder.scholarshipFile.scholarshipConfiguration.scholarshipConfigurationSelectionCriteria.scholarshipConfiguration.infoScholarshipConfiguration.scholarshipConfiguration.applicationCalendarScholarshipConfiguration.scholarshipConfiguration.studySeries.studyPromotion.studyProgrammeReference.currentRevision.programmeReference.currentRevision.entityReference.currentRevision] for NavigablePath [ro.rpss.foundations.persistence.scholarship.entity.ScholarshipHolder.scholarshipFile.scholarshipConfiguration.scholarshipConfigurationSelectionCriteria.scholarshipConfiguration.infoScholarshipConfiguration.scholarshipConfiguration.applicationCalendarScholarshipConfiguration.scholarshipConfiguration.studySeries.studyPromotion.studyProgrammeReference.currentRevision.programmeReference.currentRevision.entityReference.currentRevision] 
IP: D:31-10-2024 10:49:01.922 [main] [39mDEBUG[0;39m org.hibernate.orm.sql.ast.create - Registration of TableGroup [org.hibernate.sql.ast.tree.from.LazyTableGroup@37a65331] with identifierForTableGroup [ro.rpss.foundations.persistence.scholarship.entity.ScholarshipHolder.scholarshipFile.scholarshipConfiguration.scholarshipConfigurationSelectionCriteria.scholarshipConfiguration.infoScholarshipConfiguration.scholarshipConfiguration.applicationCalendarScholarshipConfiguration.scholarshipConfiguration.studySeries.studyPromotion.studyProgrammeReference.currentRevision.programmeReference.currentRevision.entityReference.externalReference] for NavigablePath [ro.rpss.foundations.persistence.scholarship.entity.ScholarshipHolder.scholarshipFile.scholarshipConfiguration.scholarshipConfigurationSelectionCriteria.scholarshipConfiguration.infoScholarshipConfiguration.scholarshipConfiguration.applicationCalendarScholarshipConfiguration.scholarshipConfiguration.studySeries.studyPromotion.studyProgrammeReference.currentRevision.programmeReference.currentRevision.entityReference.externalReference] 
IP: D:31-10-2024 10:49:01.922 [main] [39mDEBUG[0;39m org.hibernate.orm.sql.ast.create - Registration of TableGroup [org.hibernate.sql.ast.tree.from.LazyTableGroup@eea23a8] with identifierForTableGroup [ro.rpss.foundations.persistence.scholarship.entity.ScholarshipHolder.scholarshipFile.scholarshipConfiguration.scholarshipConfigurationSelectionCriteria.scholarshipConfiguration.infoScholarshipConfiguration.scholarshipConfiguration.applicationCalendarScholarshipConfiguration.scholarshipConfiguration.studySeries.studyPromotion.studyProgrammeReference.currentRevision.programmeReference.currentRevision.studyCycleReference] for NavigablePath [ro.rpss.foundations.persistence.scholarship.entity.ScholarshipHolder.scholarshipFile.scholarshipConfiguration.scholarshipConfigurationSelectionCriteria.scholarshipConfiguration.infoScholarshipConfiguration.scholarshipConfiguration.applicationCalendarScholarshipConfiguration.scholarshipConfiguration.studySeries.studyPromotion.studyProgrammeReference.currentRevision.programmeReference.currentRevision.studyCycleReference] 

The properties related to postgres / jpa
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://......:5432/database
spring.datasource.username=....
spring.datasource.password=......
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults=false
spring.data.jpa.repositories.bootstrap-mode=lazy
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=none
spring.jpa.database=POSTGRESQL
spring.datasource.platform=postgres
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver

spring.jpa.generate-ddl=false
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none

In pom I added the postgres dependency:
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

And the version used seems to be 42.6.0
Does anyone know what the problem could be?
